# using pgrep for process counting in a script

Tags: grep, sh

In my Raspbian I've used the command:

```
pgrep -c ^
```

I think this command should do the counting of all processes without using the more habitual method

```
ps -A --no-headers | wc -l
```

However, when run pgrep -c ^ on a script, (let's say on login), I want to subtract 1 to the counted number of running processes so that invoked shell (say "sh") running the script (or the script itself) does not count as a process... I don't know if you are following me on this. Then I begun doing some experiments with pgrep command

Here an example of my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps1=$(pgrep -c ^)
ps2=$(expr $(pgrep -c ^) - 1)    # minus 1
ps3=$(expr $(pgrep -c ^) - 2)    # minus 2
echo ${ps1}
echo ${ps2}                      # ps1 == ps2
echo ${ps3}
```

I get the results (in my case):

```
112
112
111
```

a) In the Script, changing the evaluation order of ps1 and ps2 does not make any difference. The point is that ps1 and ps2 are always equal (don't know why).

b) The same commands input directly on the prompt like this:

```
$> pgrep -c ^; expr $(pgrep -c ^) - 1
```

shows (as expected):

```
111
110
```

c) But if I modify the command to use echo:

```
$> echo "$(pgrep -c ^) : $(expr $(pgrep -c ^) - 1)"
```

even changing the evaluation order:

```
"$> echo "$(expr $(pgrep -c ^) - 1) : $(pgrep -c ^)"
```

in both cases, as in the script, I get:

```
112 : 112
```

Questions:

1) Why outside the script/echo it work as expected, but inside the script or inside and echo/printf the values are the same?

2) Is the command pgrep -c ^ the right one to count the running processes as I want to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're ignoring the fact that shells create a separate process by forking themselves for performing each command substitution.

I admit that the way shells behave is confusing though. Like, take this for example:

```
$ pstree $$
sh───pstree
$ echo $(pstree $$)
sh───pstree
```

Alhough I said otherwise above, it seems like `sh` didn't create an extra process for performing the command substitution. But, that's a misapprehension; it actually did fork, but since there is only one command in `$()`, there was no point in the forked process staying alive; so it simply replaced itself with `pstree` by calling a function from exec* family; i.e it became `pstree`.
If there were another command to be executed after `pstree` terminates, it would be necessary for the forked process to stay alive. See:

```
$ echo $(pstree $$; :)
sh───sh───pstree
```

The expansion of nested command substitutions may also be confusing, so let's clarify that too.

```
$ echo $(echo $(pstree $$))
sh───sh───pstree
```

For the example above, as each command substitution contains only one command, one might expect to see only one `sh` in the process tree; but that's not how it works. Commands enclosed in `$()` are processed in the subshell created for performing the command substitution, not in the parent shell. For this case that means; the forked process made another copy of itself to be able to both execute `pstree` and collect its output, and then executed `echo`; i.e the forked process was alive while `pstree` were running, hence the extra `sh` in the tree.

So, instead of dealing with these exceptions (and possible others that I don't know of or remember), rely on your shell's process grouping mechanism. Like:

```
pgrep -c ^
pgrep -cvg $$
echo $(pgrep -cvg $$)
echo $(echo $(pgrep -cvg $$))
echo $(echo $(echo $(pgrep -cvg $$)))
```

For me, it outputs:

```
264
263
263
263
263
```